# Prove that if a graph contains a $K_{5}$ minor, then it's not planar

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I've been having a bit of trouble trying to prove this. I don't want an answer to this question (it's an assignment problem), just some assistance on how to proceed.

I know that in order to prove that a graph is non-planar, we have to show that it contains a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

In order to show this, we must then show that there exists a set of 5 vertices such that there are 4 disjoint paths between each one and the other four (where each internal vertex in these paths has degree 2), or that there exist six vertices such that there exist disjoint paths from three of them to the other three (each internal vertex has degree 2).

I'm just not sure how I would go about showing the above.

Comment: do you know how to prove that $K_5$ itself is not planar?

Comment: $\ldots\,$and do you know how to show that if a graph is not planar if it has a minor that is not planar?

Comment: @WillJagy: Yes, I do. But I don't think I would have to prove that. That is a result already given to us in class.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I don't know how to show this. Would appreciate some hints.

Comment: @The_Questioner : If you embed a graph in a plane, then deleting or contracting an edge yields a graph that's still embeded in a plane. So minors of planar graphs are planar. Or as it's sometimes expressed, the class of planar graphs is "downwardly closed".

Comment: $\ldots\,$so if you have a graph that has $K_5$ as a minor, then it can't be planar unless $K_5$ is planar.

Comment: BTW, $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ are called the "forbidden minors" of the class of planar graphs. Every downwardly closed class of graphs consists of those whose minors are not among the forbidden minors of that class. The Robertson--Seymour theorem says for every such class, the set of forbidden minors is finite.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thank You. I appreciate the help.